# What's the "right" way of getting DefinitelyTyped typescript definition files in a .net core project?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, definitelytyped

Under asp.net for .net framework, I used to use nuget to import typescript type definitions 3rd party libraries.  (`*.d.ts`)  These packages are from [DefinitelyTyped](http://definitelytyped.org/).  I understand in the new world of .net core, nuget is no longer intended to be used for non-.net assemblies.

So is there a good way of getting typescript definitions into an mvc project?  Right now, I'm going to the github repo, and downloading the ones I need manually using a web browser.  There *has* to be a better way.

Comment: [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings)

Comment: @Granga: I guess I'm going to have to learn more about `npm` then.  Presently, the instructions fail on the first line with "'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,  operable program or batch file."  I'm pretty sure it's actually installed somewhere, but i haven't used it directly for anything.

Comment: [TypeScript 2.0 will have it built-in](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/)

Comment: @recursive, yes, npm for JS is what nuget is for .NET
I've also noticed someone answered your question in the [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/typescript/1542/importing-external-libraries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using TypeScript 2.0? If so, try to follow the instructions here: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/consumption.html. Basically there are "special" npm packages you can install with the types.

If you're not using TypeScript 2.0, are you using Gulp to compile your TS code? If so, you can simply do:

```
var typings = require("gulp-typings");
gulp.task("typings", function ()
{
    return gulp.src("./typings.json")
        .pipe(typings());
});
```

This will put all the typings you specify in your typings.json file into a /typings folder.

If you're using grunt instead there is a grunt-typings npm package and I'm sure you can find similar packages for other build runners as well.